# Permanent reboot after removing grub

Tags: boot, grub, bios

Installed Kubuntu yesterday. In the end of the process Grub installation failed. However, after a reboot, GRUB command line appeared. Then I try to boot from usb, but no success. "System BootOrder not found" after "exit" command.

Can't even access BIOS, tried fwsetup - fail.

Answer (score 2):

GRUB is the bootloader, without some bootloader, your system won't start.

You should be able to access the BIOS and to boot from USB or CD.

Comment: Yesterday, when the problem appeared for the first time, I booted from Win usb, and tried fixmbr, rebuildbcd and one more command. Nothing changed. Then tried to install Linux. With both Win and GRUB (which I can't properly install) bootloaders  installed, I couldn't get into BIOS and load OS. Idk what happened :C

Answer (score 0):

The message "system bootorder not found" makes me thing the system probably has UEFI instead of traditional BIOS. This distinction is important: it changes a lot of things in the early boot procedure.

Try typing `fwsetup` to the GRUB prompt: if it is an UEFI version of GRUB, that command should cause the system to reboot into UEFI settings (a.k.a. "access BIOS").

If you get to the boot order settings, there might be a boot entry named something like  "Windows Boot Manager": move it to the first place in the boot order. That should be enough to get you to Windows.

Comment: fwsetup does not work :C